# How to save and execute script as function in MongoDB?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongo-shell

In each deploy of our system, we have some mongodb scripts that we run in NoSQL Manager via Shell.
By running the scripts remotely, they have performance issues when we need to use cursors.

Is it possible to save a script as a function in mongo and run it calling via shell?

I managed to save it as a function, but when I run it, an error similar to the following error occurs:

```
// Command #1 1:1 0,007 s
uncaught exception: SyntaxError: unexpected token: identifier :
DB.prototype.loadServerScripts/<@src/mongo/shell/db.js:1310:29
DBQuery.prototype.forEach@src/mongo/shell/query.js:512:9
DB.prototype.loadServerScripts@src/mongo/shell/db.js:1308:5
@(shell):1:1
// Command #2 2:1 0,003 s
uncaught exception: ReferenceError: findProductFunctionTest is not defined :
@(shell):1:1
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bOLA1.png)

**Performed step by step:**

1. Save the script as a function:

```
db.system.js.insertOne(
    {
        _id: "findProductFunctionTest",
        value : function() 
        { 
            try
            {
                var produto = db.Produto.findOne({Nome: /como treinar/i});
                if (produto == null)
                    throw new Error("Produto não encontrado!");
                return produto.Nome;
            }
            catch (ex)
            {
                printjson("Erro ao processar! Exceção: " + ex.message);
            }
        }
    }
);
```

2. Load script from local server, via shell command:

```
db.loadServerScripts();
```

3. Call function, via shell command:

```
findProductFunctionTest();
```

Comment: I don't think this will solve your performance issue, did you read [the documentation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/store-javascript-function-on-server/)? *"Do not store application logic in the database. There are performance limitations to running JavaScript inside of MongoDB. Application code also is typically most effective when it shares version control with the application itself."* Anyway, such function must be pure JavaScript, however `db.Produto.findOne` is a method in mongo shell `mongosh`.

Comment: @Wernfried Domscheit, Thank you for your attention and clarification. It really makes a lot of sense for the function to only accept pure JavaScript instead of also accepting mongosh commands.
I believe that the only alternative will be to save the script in a .js file and run it via promp with a direct call to the file.

Comment: Yes, that's the normal way of doing it.